# If $3\mid mn$, then $3\mid m$ or $3\mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

I'm currently studying proofs and fundamentals, I'm reading a book by my own and I saw this problem.

**Theorem** Let $m$ and $n$ be integers. If $3\mid mn$, then $3\mid m$ or $3\mid n$.

My proof was the following:

**Proof** Suppose that$m$ and $n$ are integers such that $3$ does not divide $m$ and $n$. For that, we know that $3$ is not a factor of $m$ and $3$ is not a factor of $n$. We observe that $mn$ is the factors of $m$ times the factors of $n$. So $3$ is not a factor of $mn$. Hence, $3$ does not divide $mn$. Therefore, by the contrapositive, we deduce that if $3$ divides $mn$, then $3$ divides $m$ or $3$ divides $n$.

Is this proof enough? It doesn't sound formally enough to me? Any suggestions? Thank you!

**PS** I'm not assuming the Euclid's lemma, so I am focusing on a proof without using this result

Comment: It is true if and only if $a$ is prime.

Comment: There’s one additional assumption missing. $a$ has to be prime

Comment: My mistake, $a$ is prime, in fact is equal to $3$, I'm editing

Comment: What would do wrong if you replaced $3$ by $4$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng because it has to be a prime number 4|4 but 4 does not divide 2 for example

Comment: Your "proof" also "works" for the counterexample provided by @paw88789. So it is not okay.

Comment: @drhab it's true, it was a mistake of mine, I already edited, thank you

Comment: Good, but where does your argument **use** the fact that $3$ is prime?

Comment: " I'm not assuming the Euclid's lemma, so I am focusing on a proof without using this result" Why?  This is a single instance of Euclids lemma  You can reinvent the wheel and just reprove Euclids lemma for a single case which is .... spinning wheels.... or you can hope there is something magical about the number $3$ that makes this true for a reason other than Euclid's Lemma; which is .... hope.  Neither one of those are useful strategies.

Comment: 1)"We observe that mn is the factors of m times the factors of n."  That is either false or meaningless. The factors of $6$ are $1,2,3,6$ and the factors of $5$ are $1,5$ and yet $30=5\cdot 6$ but the factors of $6$ times the factors of $5$ are $1*2*3*6*1*5 = 180$.  2) So what if three is not a factor of $m$ nor a factor of $n$? It could be a *product* of a factor of $m$ times a factor of $n$.  You, yourself, just said all factors are product of it so... why can $3$ not be???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after the edit, I think your proof is not quite right.  In essence you are trying to prove a consequence of Euclid's lemma by arguing that when $3$ does not divide both $m$ and $n$ then it cannot divide $mn$.  That conclusion depends on $3$ being a prime number, and implicit in your logic is that $mn$ can be decomposed into a factorisation of primes.  These ideas usually follow rather than precede Euclid's lemma.  What is missing is the greatest common divisor rule, Bezout's identity.

The normal approach is

1. Establish Bezout's identity:  for any two integers $a,b$ not both zero, there is a common factor $d$ and integers $x,y$ such that $d=ax+by $ and for every common divisor of $a,b$ divides $d$.  This is proved by induction on $n = a+b$.
2. Establish $d$ is unique up to its sign and define define the greatest common divisor as the unique $d > 0$.
3. Prove Euclid's lemma:  If $a$ and $b$ have no common factors and $a| bc$ then $a | c$.
4. Define primes as the positive integers $p > 1$ that only have positive divisors $1$ and $p$.  Prove that for any $a$ if the prime $p$ does not divide $a$ then the highest common factor of $a$ and $p$ is $1$.
5. The last step is to prove your result: if the prime number $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.  The proof is an immediate consequence of Euclid's lemma $(3)$ but can also be proved without explicitly using it by mimicking its proof, as follows,

Suppose $p \not | ~a$.  Then by $(4)$ the highest common factor is $1$ and by $(1)$ there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $$1 = ax+py.$$  Then
$$b=axb+pby$$
and $p$ divides both terms on the right because $p|ab$ and $p|pby$.  Hence $p|b$.

Comment: I was thinking about your answer and search a little about it and I understood! Thank you! It happens that in the book I'm reading, this results appears without mention Bezout's Identity, g.d.c. and Euclid's lemma. So I was thinking that this could be done without mention these topics. Although I think it's better doing this way

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if a prime $p$ divides a product $mn$, then $p$ divides one factor $m$ or $n$.

Suppose $p$ doesn't divide $n$.
Then $gcd(p,n)=1$ and so $1 = ap + bn$. Thus $m = amp + bmn$.
Since $p$ divides the right hand side (since $p$ divides $mn$), it divides the left hand side $m$.

Comment: Understood! Thank you! But is there any chance to prove this without mention of g.d.c. and Bezout's Identity?